# Crop a TriangleMesh

Tags: java, 3d, javafx, mesh, java-3d

I'm able to load a TriangleMesh from a .stl file. I can draw it and everything is fine. However, things get complicated when I need to "crop" this TriangleMesh from a shape. I would like a method that looks like:

```
public TriangleMesh cropFrom(Shape shape) {
    TriangleMesh croppedTriangleMesh = new TriangleMesh();

    for (Point point : currentTriangleMesh.getPoints()) {
        if ( shape.contains(point) ) {
            // Let the magic happens!
        }
    }

    return croppedTriangleMesh;
}
```

I know that TriangleMesh works with points (x, y, z), faces and texture coordinates. I don't know how to retrieve related faces and texture coordinates given a point (or vice-versa). I don't know exactly how to start or where to look at. It does not seem to be a popular topic.

Thank you for your time and help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look into boolean operations with polygonal meshes. It is generally a hard operation, which can be done easily but not robustly, such as the following method:

- Split all the intersecting surfaces of the two objects
- Either using raytracing or using adjacency information, identify which surfaces are inside and outside in either object
- Finally, based on which operation is required, keep only selected surfaces

  - Intersection - keep perts of A inside B and parts of B inside A
  - Union - keep perts of A outside B and parts of B outside A
  - Difference A - B - keep parts of A outside B, keep parts of B inside A (and flip normal)

Alternately, there are methods using multiple precision arithmetics and conversion of polygonal objects to boundary plane representation, which are slower and difficult to implement.

It is best to use one of the libraries, implementing this, such as [CGAL](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Nef_3/index.html#Chapter_3D_Boolean_Operations_on_Nef_Polyhedra) (one of many).